# Accessing data imported into RavenDB via CSV import

Tags: csv, geospatial, ravendb, ravendb-studio

I have successfully imported geodata (originally from a shapefile, converted to CSV) into my RavenDB. I am now trying to access the data with a naive, simplistic select (sanity check to see if everything's there) but I can't get any data member values back. Since I am a total RavenDB newbie and haven't created the data myself (programmatically), my approach was to define a class that has the same name as what I find in Raven Studio (minus the automatically-appended plural 's') under Raven-Entity-Name, and to declare each of the data members to be of type string.
The query runs through and retrieves the first 128 results, but all the data members are null. I used this:

```
List<AdministrativeArea> AdministrativeArea = session
.Query<AdministrativeArea>()
.ToList();
```

Looking at the entries in Raven Studio, I can see that some of the data member values of the documents are coloured blue (so are probably already type-cast to be integer) but that shouldn't be the cause of ALL the data members showing up as null...
No exceptions are being thrown, and the query list contains elements. What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It appears that I had a problem with data types for the data members; I took the Raven Studio-generated code to define the class, but had to change two int fields to string. Seems to work now but feels hackish. Raven Studio definitely shows the values in blue, and they are numbers. Any ideas ?

Comment: Without showing the actual data and the generated class, it is very hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the instantiation of int data members. Even when declaring the int members to be nullable, the problem of empty strings came up and prevented correct instantiation of the objects.
I supose that when CSV imports are used, and in some of the cases the field/data member comes up "empty" (but as a string type), and in other cases, you DO have numbers, then you have to resort to declaring them all to be strings. The only other solution I could think of is to adapt the CSV import code, for which I am still too new to RavenDB to think about.